# Not able to Retrieve Managed Custom Field Translations using Metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api, custom-field, translation, translation-workbench

We are working on a task where we need to retrieve and update **custom field translations** using Metadata API.

The code is working fine for **unmanaged** custom fields, but for **managed** custom fields, it's giving an error during **retrieval**.

When we dug into the responses, we found that the **readMetadata** operation on the **CustomObjectTranslation** class does not return the custom fields from the managed package. However, the strange is we also tried the **updateMetadata** operation using the same class, and the update was successful.

So, Metadata API cannot retrieve managed custom field translations but can update them. Why so?

Is there a solution to be able to **retrieve managed custom field translations** problem in the current version of Metadata API? If not, is the coming version going to solve it?

---

**Also, on the same lines we not able to retrieve the below managed translations too?**

- managed custom application NAME translations
- managed custom tab NAME translations
- managed validation rule ERROR MESSAGE translations
- managed custom links/buttons NAME translations

---

Disclosure: This is for an app [Quick Update Translations](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=fa9afbfe-74ff-4027-ac32-2cdfd58184d3) live on AppExchange which enables not only Custom Label and their translation update but also supports translation updates for a variety of entities like Custom Fields, Validation Rules, Custom Tabs, Custom Applications, and Custom Links/Buttons.

Comment: On the same lines, we are not able to find a solution to retrieve managed translations (and overridden values) for Custom Applications, Custom Tabs, Validation Rules, and Custom Links/Buttons. Please advise!

Comment: Attempted to contact the Metadata API product team through a support case, but encountered difficulties as it took over a month to receive a satisfactory response.

SF reply: "Use case for getting translations of entities from managed package (ie managed package entity translations) & also for getting their (managed package entities) overriden values might not be possible and currently it's a limitation either through Metadata API or even through Apex."

Sharing here in case we missing something or other Metadata API experts here can advise!